# Android Cursor Displaying over keyboard

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm having an issue with the EditText cursor still displaying when they keyboard scrolls over the cursor.

[image]

This is the style that is applied to the EditText:

```
<style name="xyzEditTextInput" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/textPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/textHintPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/textHintPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/accent</item> 
</style>
```

This is the TextInputLayout with the EditText:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/my_input_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:errorEnabled="true"
    app:errorTextAppearance="@style/xyzEditTextError">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/my_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/pad"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textSize="@dimen/size"
        app:theme="@style/xyzEditTextInput"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```